# Can I use uint256_t in EOS smart contracts?

Tags: smart-contract, eosio-code, c++

I want to use uint256_t in my EOS smart contract but I am getting following error

```
unknown type name 'uint256_t'; did you mean 'uint16_t'?
```

I thought EOS supports uint256_t as I read it in some EOS documentation. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find that piece of documentation again!

This [Reddit link](https://www.reddit.com/r/EOSDev/comments/9gu0f8/help_what_is_eos_c_equivalent_of_uint256_of/) also says the uint256_t is supported! Did I miss something?

Comment: `uint256_t` is not actually defined in eosio. if you want a third party library for this see [this](https://github.com/playerone-id/biginteger-for-eosio#what_is_this)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/docs/using-multi-index-tables), you can use the `uint256_t` type, for instance, as secondary index of a multi index table. [Here](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/contracts/eosiolib/multi_index.hpp) you can find an example (is commented).

Answer (score 0):

`uint256_t` is not provided in eos, you may use `boost::multiprecision` to get a typedef for `uint256_t`

Answer (score 0):

The ethereum virtual machine on EOSIO allows up to 1024 bit precision for integers and can be directly used in your smart contracts with not so much bloat: https://github.com/jafri/eosio.evm/tree/master/eosio.evm/external/intx